# Azure packge com.microsoft.azure:adal4j:1.6.7 resolve error due to Jcenter being down

Tags: azure, jcenter

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':lib-provider:compileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve net.minidev:json-smart:[1.3.2,2.4.2].
     Required by:
         project :lib-provider > com.microsoft.azure:adal4j:1.6.7 > com.nimbusds:oauth2-oidc-sdk:9.4
```

There's a transitive dependency here. For this, I'm adding exclude group: 'net.minidev', module: 'json-smart' and this fixes the build error.
Is it safe to use this?
The latest package com.microsoft.azure:adal4j:1.6.7  still depends upon jCenter() and cannot resolve net.minidev.json-smart. This is because jCenter() is down. How can we solve this issue?

There's a transitive dependency here. For this, I'm adding exclude group: 'net.minidev', module: 'json-smart' and this fixes the build error.

But I'm not sure if this is okay to do and if it can cause some runtime problems.